# How to schedule @RabbitListener

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

As per the requirement, I don't want to consume message from queue for a couple of hours in a day.

```
/*Consume time from 9AM to 5PM*/
@Scheduled(cron = "* * 9-16 * * *")
@RabbitListener(queues = "${QUEUE_NAME}")
public void processMessage(SomeMessage message) {

}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution ? we have same requirement.

Comment: So as per our requirement, to stop processing messages from the main queue from 8pm to 6am.
So we did it in publisher where we check time while publishing the message, if its between 8pm to 6am then we publishing that message in a different queue to process letter. That queue configured with ttl=36000000 (8pm to 6am = 10hrs) to hold it and then pass the message to the main queue after that is over.
So if request coming at 8:01pm it'll be processed at 6:01am and if request coming at 5:59am then processed 3:59pm.
We have no issue on that message if we process that later.

Answer (score 4):

I see a few options

## Keep your application started just when consumption is required

The application could be started by cron (or other schedulers) and once started, schedule itself to stop after some time.

## Consume messages in an imperative, not declarative way.

Just use https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/#polling-consumer

Use 
org.springframework.amqp.coreAmqpTemplate#receive method in a loop. Make sure that your loop is running only during scheduled hours.

## Use Delayed Messages

https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/delayed-messages.html

This requires changes in the producer. The consumer could be running all the time. But if during sending the message you delay it, so it will be delivered according to your schedule.